# .ashx handler not getting gzip compressed despite IIS Config setting

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, gzip

I have a handler in my sitecore site that's beeing used on all of the pages.  The site is gzip-compressed via web.config settings, and all other files show the proper headers to indicate gzip compression.  But Google Analytics Page Speed Suggestions is reporting this one handler file as not being compressed.  Any way to get this file also to be gzip-encoded?  It inherits from IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState.

Comment: If you're serving images through ashx file, then you need to make sure you're setting up correct mime type upon response. That way IIS dynamicCompression (if enabled) would apply GZip.

Comment: Not serving images through this, just textual content - json.