# IIS does not seem to be compressing response created by ashx

Tags: asp.net, .net, gzip, ashx

I have an ashx handler, and the response is not gzipped. The content-encoding received by the client is empty.

The IIS settings for the site have static and dynamic compression enabled.

Research of similar problems shows some people have an `httpCompression` node in the web server node of IIS configuration editor. I do not have such a node. I have a url compression node, where I have set everything to true. Perhaps that is IIS version dependent. The  op system is Windows Server 2008 R2.

I am about to try to "force" compression using the filter property and the `GZipstream` class (credit to Rick Strahl's blog). If anyone can tell my why IIS is not "auto compressing" or can point to any gotchas in my workaround I would be grateful.

**Update:** attaching `GzipStream` to the response filter reduced the content length by half as seen by the client, which seems to indicate the "manual" compression is doing something.

I am aware this was previously asked here:

> [.ashx handler not getting gzip compressed despite IIS Config setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413050/ashx-handler-not-getting-gzip-compressed-despite-iis-config-setting)

However, the previous question did not receive any answers, so I am asking the question again.

Comment: are u adding "Accept-Encoding", "gzip" in request headers while making HTTP request ?

Comment: I think so but I will check when I get back to the office. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are correct. I was not setting the Accept-Encoding header in the request. d'oh! Thanks very much. Although having seen how easy it is to compress/uncompress in code, I think I will stick with that. It gives me complete control over what gets compressed and what does not.

Comment: @user123456 if you repost your comment as an answer I will indicate it is the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you are adding Accept-Encoding", "gzip" in request headers while making HTTP request.